# Reactive Spring: How to pass Access Token from OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code Flow to scheduled task

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-webflux, spring-oauth2

I'm trying to build an application that periodically fetches data from a Third-Party API that demands a reCAPTCHA protected **OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code Flow with PKCE** for authentication.
I guess, it wouldn't be a big deal to implement the authorization protocol manually but I'm willing to do that using the **Spring Security OAuth Client** in the **reactive** manner.

The goal is to have a **scheduled task** that fetches the data from the API only being blocked until I manually open up a **login page** (currently a REST endpoint) in the browser that forwards me to the login page of the API vendor. After successful authentication, the scheduled task should also be able to access the API.

Currently the class structure looks like this:

[image: Class diagramm]

`MyController#showData` and `MyScheduler#fetchData` both call `ApiClient#retrieveData` which does the final API call using the reactive `WebClient` from Spring.

The `WebClient` configuration looks like this:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
class WebClientConfiguration {

    @Bean
    WebClient webClient(ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegs, 
            ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService authClientService) {
        ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authClientManager =
            new AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(clientRegs, authClientService);
        ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth =
            new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authClientManager);
        oauth.setDefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClient(true);
        oauth.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("test");
        return WebClient.builder()
          .filter(oauth)
          .build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http,
            ServerOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver resolver) {
        http.authorizeExchange()
          .anyExchange()
          .authenticated()
          .and()
          .oauth2Login(auth -> auth.authorizationRequestResolver(resolver));
        return http.build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public ServerOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver pkceResolver(
            ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository repo) {
        DefaultServerOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver resolver = 
            new DefaultServerOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver(repo);
        resolver.setAuthorizationRequestCustomizer(OAuth2AuthorizationRequestCustomizers.withPkce());
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

**The authorization works fine.** When I open `/showData` in the browser, I'm redirected to the vendor's login page and when I come back, the requested data is displayed as it should be.

**But the Scheduler is still blocked.** I guess that has something to do with the Security Context which is linked only to the browser session, but I'm not so familiar with Spring Security to understand how to share the access (and refresh) token within the whole application.

*Disclaimer: The Third-Party API has specific endpoints which are explicitly meant to be called periodically and not only on a user's request, but they still demand authorization by Authorization Code instead of Client Credential.*

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call third-party API from the scheduler you should pass  [OAuth2AuthorizedClient](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/OAuth2AuthorizedClient.html) to it. That class represent an OAuth2 authorized client and has information about access/refresh token.
Here is the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/oauth2/client/authorized-clients.html) describing how to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I managed to do an authorized request from the Scheduler by setting the AuthorizedClient as request attribute. But somehow the refresh of the access token don't work, although there is a refresh token available.